# How do I write a formula using a picklist and a date field?

Tags: formula, picklist

I have a picklist field for "Interview Applicable" with the choices being "Yes" or "No".  I also have a date field for "Scheduled Interview".  I have a third field that is a text field.  I'm trying to write a formula for the text field that will give me "NA" if Interview Applicable is "No" and the Scheduled Interview date if Interview Applicable is "Yes".  I keep tweaking the formula but continue getting a syntax error message.  Below is one version of the formula I've tried.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Interview_Applicable_c, "No"), "NA",
IF(ISPICKVAL(Interview_Applicable_c, "Yes"), "Scheduled_Interview_c"))
```

Comment: I tried the formula below but received the following error message: Error: Field Interview_Applicable__c may not be used in this type of formula.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the type of the formula field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing, which may have just been accidental when writing your question is that those custom fields should have two underscores in their name `_ _ c`.

Second, this should work for you.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Interview_Applicable__c, "Yes"), 
    TEXT(MONTH(Scheduled_Interview__c)) + "/" +
    TEXT(DAY(Scheduled_Interview__c)) + "/" +
    TEXT(YEAR(Scheduled_Interview__c)), "NA")
```

If the picklist value is 'yes' it converts the date field value into text and if it is <strike>'no'</strike> any other value, you receive 'NA' as the result of the formula.

[image: NA]

---

[image: Date]

---

**This formula is of the type Text**

[image: Formula Definition]

Comment: Got it working.  Thanks so much!!!  Is there any way to change the formatting of the date in the formula field so that it matches the formatting in Scheduled Interview?

Comment: @Lynn, I updated the formula to demonstrate splitting the date into the year, month and day components.

Comment: @Lynn did this solution work for you?

Comment: It worked.  Thanks again!!  You don't know how helpful this has been!

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked for you! If you could click the 'Accepted Answer' checkmark button (under the voting buttons) on this answer that would be much appreciated.